# Azure AD issuing token that contains scopes I disabled

Tags: .net, api, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to use Azure AD to restrict access to certain endpoints in my API.

I registered a FrontEnd and API app in Azure AD. When I go to disable the scopes I'm still getting the scopes issued in my oauth token.

[image: FrontEnd-Scope]

[image: Oauth-token]

Anyone have any ideas what I may be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jeff. Have you clicked Grant permissions after resetting permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may forget to reconsent for these permissions.

AAD v1 endpoint acts static permissions consent. Once you do permissions consent, the scope will be static, except you reconsent for new permissions. If you change the permissions and don't reconsent, the scope should be just as same as before.

So, you can just click Grant permissions button to reconsent permissions. Or you can just add `&prompt=admin_consent` in the request to force doing consent.

Comment: I tried Grant Permissions in the FrontEnd app after disabling Scope A but I'm still getting that scope in the token. I also tried adding the query string for consent but that didn't help either.

Comment: Also, it seems like it takes awhile for the Grant Permissions to propagate the new scopes to the user. I ask because I went to check afterwards and it seemed like the right scopes were being delivered now. Does it usually take awhile for Azure to  make this update?

Comment: Hi @Jeff , you're right. It will take seconds to update the permissions. So, is your issue resolved ?